# CATextLayer not rendering properly on SCNNode

Tags: ios, core-animation, scenekit, catextlayer, scnscene

I have a hierarchy of CALayers that I am setting as the diffuse property of my SCNNode's material. I taking snapshots of the current state of the scene (that only has the one node) to save as a PNG to a file using this code:

```
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.createLayer() // CALayer

// Set transform of node.

let renderTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1
let size = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)

let renderer = SCNRenderer(
  device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
  options: nil) 
let image = self.renderer.snapshot(
  atTime: renderTime,
  with: size,
  antialiasingMode: .multisampling4X)

return image
```

Often this works, rendering the node as expected, but about 25-50% of the time, any CATextLayer I have as a sublayer of the layer returned in `self.createLayer()` does not render the text. All other layers seem to be rendered just fine every time.

For example, an image that is supposed to look as such:

[image: correct]

Ends up missing the text "N":
[image: incorrect]

The layer itself is being rendered, as I can confirm by changing the background color of the text layer:

[image]

This seems to only be an issue that occurs immediately after creating the layers. If I dispatch the rendering code asynchronously, even without adding any delay, everything renders as expected:

```
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.createLayer() // CALayer
// Set transform of node.
let renderTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1

let size = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  let image = self.renderer.snapshot(
    atTime: renderTime,
    with: size,
    antialiasingMode: .multisampling4X)

  completion(image)
}
```

The above workaround seems hacky and I don't trust it to be reliable. Also, I'd rather not force my callsites to call the method in an asynchronous manner.

Is there a property or method in SceneKit or CoreAnimation that I'm missing that I can use to make sure the layer is completely rendered before trying to render it to an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand it is not reliable using DispatchMain as you are not sure the node has been rendered well. So there is a function tell you if the rendering has complete or not. Call snapshot inside that completion handle.

```
 scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.createLayer() // CALayer

    let renderer = SCNRenderer(
        device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
        options: nil)

----renderer.prepare([node]) { (success) in  // this line is useful
        if (success){
            let renderTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1
            let size = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)
            let  image = renderer.snapshot(
                atTime: renderTime,
                with: size,
                antialiasingMode: .multisampling4X)
            complete(image)
        }
    }
```

You may add other nodes to the array if you think it takes too long to load.

Comment: Excellent! This call isn't synchronous as I was hoping, but this is almost exactly what I was looking for! If there is a synchronous version, that would be even better, but this feels much safer than just dispatching and hoping everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success making PNG snapshots by just invoking SCNTransaction.flush() before the invoking sceneView.snapshot().

Comment: I tried adding `SCNTransaction.flush()` before creating the snapshot, but it still has the original issue where the text layers don't render the text.